# If $\,f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $\,f (7) > 2$, then $∃δ > 0$ such that $f (x) > 2 ∀x ∈ Vδ (7).$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\,f  \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $\,f (7) > 2$, then  $∃δ > 0$ such that $f(x) > 2 ∀x ∈ Vδ (7),δ $- neighborhood of $7$.

I know the definition of continuous at a point. However, the question does not specific any particular point. Will it still work?

Could anyone help get me started?

What I got so far 
For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exist δ > 0 such that whenever x in R and |x-7|< δ, it follow that |f(x) - f(7)| < |f(x) - 2|< sth that I am not sure

Am I going the right direction?

Comment: The question specifying the point 7. because we are considering $\delta$ nbd of 7.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\epsilon = \frac{ f(7) - 2 }{2}$ which is positive. apply the definition of continuity at the point 7.

Comment: How do you determine $\epsilon = \frac{ f(7) - 2 }{2}$ ?

Comment: we need not to determine $\epsilon$. we have to prove that there exists a $\delta$ satisfying the required property whose existence is assured by this $\epsilon$ and the definition of continuity.

Comment: I mean why do you set your $\epsilon = \frac{ f(7) - 2 }{2}$ in this way?

Comment: We can consider any nbd around $f(7)$ which not containing $2$. The one I said is one among uncountably many such choices.